# Desactivate text field on load, and

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have a input asp-for tag helper. I want to desactivate it when the controller loads the page ( by using a property inside, without using javascript ) and also be able to activate it by again setting a property without using the id, is that possible ?

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dn" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dn" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: With initial load we can disable input with property. But if you wanna enable; then please tell under which event you wanna enable it?  Onclick of button/checkbox? Or on change of anything?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `ViewBag.status` from the `Get` method to control the display of the input, when you click a button, pass the current form data and the value of `ViewBag.status` to controller, change the value of `ViewBag.status` and return data to view.

1.`Get` action:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.status= "InActive";
        return View();
    }
```

2.Create View:

```
<form asp-action="Create">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.status" name="status" />
            @if (ViewBag.status == "InActive")
            {
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" disabled/>
            }
            else
            {
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control"/>
            }

            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="EnableInput" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
</form>
```

3.Post Action:

```
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,LastName,FirstName,Address")] Student student)
    {
        var status = Request.Form["status"].ToString();
        if (status == "InActive")
        {
            ViewBag.status = "Active";

            return View(student);
        }
        //...
    }
```